# youtube Channel data list API for need channel owner details

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need to get owner details like email/username/name of the channel using youtube data API. I've checked the document. Can you please suggest a way how I can get these details for the same?

- Email address - emails are usually hidden by a button protected by reCaptcha

Thanks,
AR

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for [channels#resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource) you will notice that the fields you are looking for

- email
- username
- name

Do not exist there is no way to find out the owner of a YouTube channel via the YouTube API even if you are authenticated as that user. If you did authorize the user you could add the profile and email scopes and this would give you access to the Google People API and you would be able to find that information there.

If you are not authorizing the user then there is no way you are going to get private personal information about a user from a public api endpoint.